# Optimal mass transportation: how do we know a mass transportation exists?

Tags: measure-theory

Monge's mass transportation problem, or the [optimal mass transportation problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transportation_theory_(mathematics)), asks given two distributions $\mu, \nu$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with equal total mass, and a cost function $c:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, what transportation of $\mu$ to $\nu$ minimizes the cost?

My question is, how do we know there is even a single map which pushes $\mu$ forward to $\nu$? There is not an explicit construction. Furthermore this map apparently must be measurable, and I've learned proving the measurability of mappings is not so easy.

Comment: Quoting from Wikipedia, "Monge's formulation of the optimal transportation problem can be ill-posed, because sometimes there is no $T$ satisfying $\displaystyle T_{*}(\mu )=\nu$: this happens, for example, when $\mu$ is a Dirac measure but $\nu$ is not. We can improve on this by adopting Kantorovich's formulation..."